# openpyxl and excel: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, openpyxl

I know that seems that this question has been done many time, but i'm struggling with the "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' " error using openpyxl. As far as i understand it comes from a comparison btw str and int. It pops when the "not found" assingnment is done but i can't understand how i'm comparing the two wrong variables.

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsm')
sheet = workbook['Form1']
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True): 
.
.
.
.
    if not found:
            sheet.cell(row=row[0], column=21).value="not found" 
        continue
```

Comment: What is the value of `row[0]`? I would say it is a string and should be an integer.

Comment: The method `Worksheet.cell` expects an integer as the parameter `row`.
At using `iter_rows` with the flag `values_only` set to `True`, inside `row` you will have whatever is inside the current cell of the iteration.

Comment: row[0] is a string, "found" is a variable resulting from code in between

Comment: If you take a look to the [source code](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.1/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py#L242) you will see the string and integer comparison raising the error.

Comment: @JorgeLuis uh, so should i cast the value of flag "value_only" to false?

Comment: @MatteoCaruso It depends on what you want exactly to do... But I would say so. By so you will get the cells and to access its row you can use the dot notation.

Comment: The code is incomplete and looks odd. What is `found`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` to iterate over rows and row number:

```
min_row = 2

for idx, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows(min_row=min_row, values_only=True), min_row):
    ...
    if not found:
        sheet.cell(row=idx, column=21).value = "not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `row[0]` I would expect to see a string.
The method `Worksheet.cell` expects the argument `row` to be an integer.
If you take a look to the [source code](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.1/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py#L242) you will see the string and integer comparison raising the error.

As you set the argument `values_only=True` in the method `iter_rows` you get the content of the cells and not the cells.
This does not allow you to access each cell indices.
If you turn off that flag, you can do something like this:

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsm')
sheet = workbook['Form1']
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2): 
    ...
    if not found:
        sheet.cell(row=row[0].row, column=21).value="not found" 
        continue
```

You can still access the cell value by `row[column_index].value`.